# Remove Index Scan from the Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am fine tuning the following SQL Query

```
    SELECT C.zoneId                  ,
       Count(DISTINCT J.id)      ,
       Sum(BP.InstalledSubtotal) 
FROM   cust C
       INNER JOIN Jobs J
               ON J.CustomerId = C.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT GZZ.ZipAndPostalCodeId,
                                       GZZ.GeographicalZoneId,
                                       gz.DEALERId
                       FROM   GeoZip GZZ
                              INNER JOIN GeographicalZone GZ
                                      ON GZZ.GeographicalZoneId = GZ.Id) CGZ
                    ON CGZ.ZipAndPostalCodeId = C.PhysicalZipId
                       AND CGZ.DEALERId = c.DEALERId
       INNER JOIN BndProduct BP
               ON BP.TableRowId = J.id
                  AND BP.TableId = 23
                  AND BP.InstalledSubtotal <> 0
WHERE  BP.DateCreated BETWEEN 'Nov  1 2015 12:00AM' AND 'Nov 20 2015 11:59PM'
       AND ( Cast(BP.DateCreated AS DATE) <> Cast(J.ContractDate AS DATE)
              OR ( Cast(BP.DateCreated AS DATE) = Cast(J.ContractDate AS DATE)
                   AND BP.EmployeeId <> J.SalesRepId ) )
       AND ( BP.EmployeeId <> 0
             AND BP.EmployeeId IS NOT NULL )
       AND ( J.SalesRepId <> 0
             AND J.SalesRepId IS NOT NULL )
       AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM   ServLead ISL
                            INNER JOIN Appts IA
                                    ON IA.ServiceLeadId = ISL.id
                            INNER JOIN CalEve IE
                                    ON IE.TableId = 1
                                       AND IE.TableRowId = IA.id
                            INNER JOIN ApptRst IAR
                                    ON IAR.EventId = IE.id
                            INNER JOIN Job IJ
                                    ON IJ.AppointmentResultId = IAR.id
                                       AND IJ.id = J.id
                     WHERE  ( ISL.IsTemporary = 0 )
                            AND ( IA.IsTemporary = 0 )
                            AND ( IE.IsTemporary = 0 )
                            AND ( IAR.IsTemporary = 0 ))
              OR J.ProductionTypeId = 2 )
       AND ( BP.IsDeleted = 0 )
       AND ( C.IsTemporary = 0 )
       AND ( J.IsTemporary = 0 )
       AND ( C.ZoneId = 0
              OR 0 = 0 )
       AND ( CGZ.GeographicalZoneId = 0
              OR 0 = 0 )
       AND CASE '0'
             WHEN 'STATE' THEN C.PhysicalState
             WHEN '' THEN 0
             ELSE 0
           END LIKE 0
       AND C.DEALERId = 23
GROUP  BY C.zoneId
```

Please refer the execution plan.

[image]

There is one Index Scan. I don't know how to change it to index seek.

I tried with hint like the below.

```
with (forceseek)
```

but when I compared the results of normal SQL and SQL with hints. Normal SQL performs better than SQL with Hint.

Please provide me any suggestions to improvise the query.
Currently it took around 5 to 6 Secs. I trying to reduce it to 1-2 Secs.

@Devart: I have implemented your solution but it seems the same execution time.

Please check the execution plan as you requested.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This aliasing of your `FROM Object8 Object6 INNER JOIN Object9 Object7` is going to make trouble shooting a lot of fun! This seems rather counter-intuitive..... why alias at all? Doesn't make a lot of sense to me.....

Comment: So in your case Index Scan performs better than Index Seek :) Why do you want to need Index Seek here?

Comment: It's also an **index scan** - SQL Server isn't scanning the whole table - only one particular index. If that index is small (e.g. only one or few columns, only small datatypes like `INT`) this can be quite efficient, actually! And if the SQL Server query optimizer picks this operation, it probably is more efficient than forcing an index seek on something....

Comment: What is the purpose of this predicate?  `AND ( Cast(Object3.Column11 AS DATE) <> Cast(Object2.Column12 AS DATE)
          OR ( Cast(Object3.Column11 AS DATE) = Cast(Object2.Column12 AS DATE)`

Comment: Please provide a real query without anonymous code. A bit hard to understand your business logic

Comment: @DanGuzman: Date should not be equal or atleast ID should not be equal if date is matched

Comment: Hi all, I posted the actual query now. Please review and provide any suggestions now. Sorry for the anonymous code.

Comment: @NewUser, the revised query makes more sense.  Can you include the actual plan of same?

Comment: Yes I have included the actual plan

Comment: Why do you think you need to get rid of the scan? A seek is not always the best way to retrieve data (as you found out, I hope, when you tried to force it). See #2 here: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/ (And no, you didn't include an actual plan, you included a screen shot of the plan, which is not the same as the XML / .sqlplan - much more useful.)

Comment: From your image it looks that index scan has on about 3% cost which is far from being the biggest problem in the query. Can you provide us at least the cardinality for Customer and Jobs? It would be nice to also see the details obtained by hovering your mouse over that step (it shows keys, output columns etc.). It might provide some insight why the planner thinks that scan is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @t (ID)
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ IJ.id
FROM ServLead ISL
JOIN Appts IA ON IA.ServiceLeadId = ISL.id
JOIN CalEve IE ON IE.TableId = 1 AND IE.TableRowId = IA.id
JOIN ApptRst IAR ON IAR.EventId = IE.id
JOIN Job IJ ON IJ.AppointmentResultId = IAR.id
WHERE ISL.IsTemporary = 0
    AND IA.IsTemporary = 0
    AND IE.IsTemporary = 0
    AND IAR.IsTemporary = 0

SELECT C.zoneId,
       COUNT(DISTINCT J.id),
       SUM(BP.InstalledSubtotal)
FROM cust C
JOIN Jobs J ON J.CustomerId = C.id
--LEFT JOIN (
--    SELECT DISTINCT GZZ.ZipAndPostalCodeId,
--                    GZZ.GeographicalZoneId,
--                    GZ.DEALERId
--    FROM GeoZip GZZ
--    JOIN GeographicalZone GZ ON GZZ.GeographicalZoneId = GZ.id
--) CGZ ON CGZ.ZipAndPostalCodeId = C.PhysicalZipId
--    AND CGZ.DEALERId = C.DEALERId
JOIN BndProduct BP ON BP.TableRowId = J.id
    AND BP.TableId = 23
    AND BP.InstalledSubtotal <> 0
WHERE BP.DateCreated BETWEEN '20151101 12:00AM' AND '20151120 11:59PM'
    AND (
            CAST(BP.DateCreated AS DATE) <> CAST(J.ContractDate AS DATE)
        OR (
                CAST(BP.DateCreated AS DATE) = CAST(J.ContractDate AS DATE)
            AND
                BP.EmployeeId <> J.SalesRepId)
        )
    AND BP.EmployeeId <> 0
    AND J.SalesRepId <> 0
    AND (EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @t IJ
        WHERE IJ.id = J.id
    ) OR J.ProductionTypeId = 2)
    AND BP.IsDeleted = 0
    AND C.IsTemporary = 0
    AND J.IsTemporary = 0
    AND (C.ZoneId = 0 OR 0 = 0)
    --AND (CGZ.GeographicalZoneId = 0 OR 0 = 0)
    AND C.DEALERId = 23
GROUP BY C.zoneId
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

**UPDATE** -

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
    ON dbo.ServLead (id) WHERE IsTemporary = 0
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
    ON dbo.Appts (ServiceLeadId) INCLUDE(id) WHERE IsTemporary = 0
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
    ON dbo.CalEve (TableRowId) INCLUDE(id) WHERE IsTemporary = 0 AND TableId = 1 
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
    ON dbo.ApptRst (EventId) INCLUDE(id) WHERE IsTemporary = 0
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
    ON dbo.Job (AppointmentResultId) INCLUDE(id)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.BndProduct
    ADD DateCreated_DT AS CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) PERSISTED
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Jobs
    ADD ContractDate_DT AS CAST(ContractDate AS DATE) PERSISTED
GO

DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ IJ.id
FROM dbo.ServLead ISL
JOIN dbo.Appts IA ON IA.ServiceLeadId = ISL.id
JOIN dbo.CalEve IE ON IE.TableId = 1 AND IE.TableRowId = IA.id
JOIN dbo.ApptRst IAR ON IAR.EventId = IE.id
JOIN dbo.Job IJ ON IJ.AppointmentResultId = IAR.id
WHERE ISL.IsTemporary = 0
    AND IA.IsTemporary = 0
    AND IE.IsTemporary = 0
    AND IAR.IsTemporary = 0
--OPTION(RECOMPILE)

DECLARE @c TABLE
(
    ZipAndPostalCodeId INT,
    DEALERId INT,
    GeographicalZoneId INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ZipAndPostalCodeId, DEALERId, GeographicalZoneId)
)
INSERT INTO @c (ZipAndPostalCodeId, GeographicalZoneId, DEALERId)
SELECT DISTINCT GZZ.ZipAndPostalCodeId,
                GZZ.GeographicalZoneId,
                GZ.DEALERId
FROM dbo.GeoZip GZZ
JOIN dbo.GeographicalZone GZ ON GZZ.GeographicalZoneId = GZ.id

SELECT C.zoneId,
       COUNT(DISTINCT J.id),
       SUM(BP.InstalledSubtotal)
FROM dbo.cust C
JOIN dbo.Jobs J ON J.CustomerId = C.id
LEFT JOIN @c CGZ ON CGZ.ZipAndPostalCodeId = C.PhysicalZipId AND CGZ.DEALERId = C.DEALERId
JOIN dbo.BndProduct BP ON BP.TableRowId = J.id
WHERE BP.DateCreated BETWEEN '20151101 12:00AM' AND '20151120 11:59PM'
    AND (
            BP.DateCreated_DT <> J.ContractDate_DT
        OR (
                BP.DateCreated_DT = J.ContractDate_DT
            AND
                BP.EmployeeId <> J.SalesRepId)
        )
    AND BP.EmployeeId <> 0
    AND BP.TableId = 23
    AND BP.InstalledSubtotal <> 0
    AND J.SalesRepId <> 0
    AND (J.id IN (SELECT t.ID FROM @t t) OR J.ProductionTypeId = 2)
    AND BP.IsDeleted = 0
    AND C.IsTemporary = 0
    AND J.IsTemporary = 0
    AND (C.ZoneId = 0 OR 0 = 0)
    AND (CGZ.GeographicalZoneId = 0 OR 0 = 0)
    AND C.DEALERId = 23
GROUP BY C.zoneId
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Happy New Year Thanks for your solution

Comment: thanks :) please provide your execution plan for this query

Comment: I tried your solution but the time taken is almost same. Please tell me if you find any other optimal way. I will vote up for your answer.

Comment: @NewUser please provide your new execution plan... thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated the execution plan of the solution you provided.